# Extensions May not contain Stored properties

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

Can I implement this in Swift with Extensions without the need to inheritance?. 
I get this error 
Extensions May not contain Stored properties

```
extension UIButton
{
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : CGFloat
        {
        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can override the setter/getter so that it isn't a stored property and just forwards the set/get to the layer.

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }

        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This technic works but it doesn't update the UI in the xib/storyboard.

Comment: Do `setNeedsLayout()` after setting.

Answer (score 16):

Extensions cannot add stored properties. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) (Computed Properties section):

> Note
>
> Extensions can add new computed properties, but they cannot add stored
>   properties, or add property observers to existing properties.

If you have a need for stored properties, you should create a subclass, like so:

```
class CustomButton : UIButton
{
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : CGFloat
        {
        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to store variable I want to change  layer.borderWidth from interface builder

Comment: dan's answer might work for you then, though my concern is that the `UIButton` might not be fully initialized before the getter/setter is invoked.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift, I'm importing a static library written in Objective-C. The protocol below, in that library, has a method and a property.

```
@class Message;

@protocol LocalService 

@property (readonly) int action;

- (Message *)getResponse:(Message *)request;

@end
```

Trying to have a class conform to that protocol, delivers the messages below:

> 1-) Type 'ShowInitialViewLocalService' does not conform to protocol 'LocalService
>
> 2-) Extensions may not contain stored properties

The code provided below, fixes this issue:

```
import UIKit

class ShowInitialViewLocalService: NSObject{

}

extension ShowInitialViewLocalService : LocalService {
    
    var action: Int32 {
        get { return View.InitialView.rawValue }
    }
    
    func getResponse(_ request: Message) -> Message {
        let response = Response(source: request.target, target: request.source, relatedView: View.InitialView.rawValue, action: request.action, data: request.data)
        return response
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone.