# What is the correct way to add custom variables to exising classes like UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I heavily depend on different view types and they will hold different values. For example, for a button I will need it to have 4 additional variables and I implemented it like this:

```
import UIKit

class ActionButton: UIButton {

    var row = 0
    var action = 0
    var appDataId = ""
    var companyId = ""

}
```

And I use a ActionButton instead of UIButton.

However I will need a lot of these for different types of views like labels buttons etc and it might complicate the project.

My question is, is that a good practice? Is there any other way to achieve same result ?

Thanks!

Comment: [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Comment: @Desdenova, You cannot add stored properties in extension, thus this one word can't help the questioner. Ones that would are "associated objects".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**METHOD 0:** What you already showed us works fine :D

Thats is: subclassing an existing Class and customising it with your vars. You will just have to copy paste that button or set the class of newly created buttons to `ActionButton`.

But there are more interesting solutions in my opinion.

---

**METHOD 1:** Create a UIButton extension and use Associated Objects in place of stored vars.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

There is also an  alternate way:

[Extensions May not contain Stored properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337509/extensions-may-not-contain-stored-properties)

---

**METHOD 1.5 (RECOMMENDED SOLUTION):**

Make an extension of `UIView`. UILabel and UIButton as well as many other UI elements inherit from it. What you put in your `UIView` extension will be accessible to all classes that inherit from `UIView`.

---

**BONUS METHOD (if you want or need to go a step further):** Create a custom UIButton Class and use IBInspectables !

You will then be able to modify the vars directly from the Interface builder which is very handy for testing !

Example:

```
//
//  CustomButton.swift


import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            setupView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.tintColor = fontColor
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

    }
```

Comment: I think you should clarify method 1 is about making a custom class that inherits from UIButton, OP never asked about being able to edit those values directly from the interface builder. good answer anyway.

Comment: The question is about adding stored properties, isn't it?

Comment: @werediver Yup ! It's all about answering AND providing added value.

Comment: I'd move the focus from `IBInspectable` to subclassing as a way to add stored properties (btw, that can or can not satisfy the questioner depending on whether subclassing is appropriate in his case).

Comment: @werediver I am currently improving my answer ! Thx for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will use extensions.

Comment: @JacobSmith Method 1.5 is the one I would recommend :D If you have any  issues, come back and ask a question ;)

Comment: I actually do have issues. How do I create getters and setters in extensions? In the method which i used in my question, all I had to do was actionbutton.row = 3 to set, var gettedRow = actionbutton.row

I get errors like this:

Comment: I did it like this but get error:
extension UIView {
    var testRow: String
}

Comment: @JacobSmith It will be hard to answer this in the comments. Please ask another question and I will come to help you there ;) (Different issue = new question)