# Human readable tag/id for a View in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Let's say I have created a UI with some views using an interface builder (not in code, so not programmatically).

How can I assign human readable ids / tags to these views, so that I could reference them in code?

I know that I can assign an integer tag to a view using attribute inspector and then make a dictionary (or enum) to store the mapping of tags to the views. However, this is an error-prone method which also scales really badly (imaging assigning integer tags to hundred of views in a complex app...).

Is there a better solution for this problem? Is there a way to directly assign a human readable tag / id to a view, like "resumeButton"?

UPDATE: 
Here is an example scenario of what I want to achieve:

- UI with five different buttons; the buttons have image and no title
- all five buttons are connected to the same IBAction in code
- in IBAction I have a switch statement, so that depending on which button is clicked, different versions of code are executed

UPDATE 2:

**SOLUTION**

I ended up implementing a simple custom view:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {
     @IBInspectable var stringTag: String = defaultID
}
```

This way I can see an additional property `stringTag` in Interface Builder and can simply add a value to it directly in Interface Builder.

Comment: If there are 5 different actions, then you should have 5 different `IBAction` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension property on UIView to store an `identifier` string.  If you made that extension property IBInspectable, you could set and view it from the storyboard directly.

More detail on setting up such a property in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37166043/1830999

The built-in `tag` property for UIView is just an integer, so it isn't very descriptive for humans who read it.

Answer (score 2):

From what you're describing sounds to me that you are looking for an: [Outlets](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devc06f7ee11)

Comment: I know about outlets, but unfortunately I don't think they will solve my problem. I updated my question with the example scenario of what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @nauke They would solve your problem. You can switch over `sender` and every case can contain an outlet button.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about tags. Every connection with Interface Builder should be handled using `IBAction` and `IBOutlet`.

Since you say that every button has a different action, the simplest solution is to create a separate `IBAction` for each of them:

```
@IBAction private func onResumeButtonTapped() {
   ...
}

@IBAction private func onPauseButtonTapped() {
   ...
}
```

If you, for some reason, want to keep them connected to one function, you can use outlets:

```
@IBOutlet private var resumeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet private var pauseButton: UIButton!

@IBAction private func onButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   switch sender {
      case resumeButton:
         ...
      case pauseButton:
         ...
      default:
          break
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the detailed answer! Making switch statement with outlets indeed works, but accepted answer provides more general solution for what I was looking for.